# Threads and Invoking a method in Windows Service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, invoke, wmi-query

I'm implementing this project as Windows Service. I'm trying to find out the open network interfaces in local and log them. When there is an change in network interfaces newAdapterNotifier method is triggered

```
    public void newAdapterNotifier(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) //Change in network
    {
        checkNetworkAdapters();
    }
```

This method is triggered by WMI What I mean is;

```
ManagementEventWatcher watcher = null;
query = new WqlEventQuery();
query.EventClassName = "__InstanceOperationEvent";
query.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
query.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NetworkAdapter' AND TargetInstance.NetConnectionStatus IS NOT NULL";
watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(newAdapterNotifier);
```

In newAdapterNotifier I'm calling checkNetworkAdapters it is not giving any error but not working too. In WindowsForms I'm doing the same code with an only difference and it is WORKING!!!;

```
public delegate void ControlNetworkAdapter();
public void newAdapterNotifier(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) //Change in network
{
    this.Invoke(new ControlNetworkAdapter(checkNetworkAdapters));
}
```

Since there is no Invoke method in Windows Service application it is not working. How can I solve it?

FULL CODE OF THE CLASS (If there is any other network interface open while allowed is open. send Mail)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace newInternetNotifier
{
    class newNetworkInterfaceNotifier
    {
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = null;
        WqlEventQuery query;
        ManagementOperationObserver observer = new ManagementOperationObserver();
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
        DbManager sqlConn;
        string cameras1IP = "10.0.0.102";
        string cameras2IP = "10.0.0.103";

        public newNetworkInterfaceNotifier(DbManager _sqlConn)
        {
            sqlConn = _sqlConn;
            getPingableIPs();
            System.Threading.Thread thr = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
            tmr.Tick +=new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);

            stopTimer();

            checkNetworkAdapters();
            prepareEvent();
        }

        void getPingableIPs() {
            cameras1IP = sqlConn.GetScalarValue("SELECT dbo.GetIP(1)").ToString();
            cameras2IP = sqlConn.GetScalarValue("SELECT dbo.GetIP(2)").ToString();
        }

        int elapsedTime;
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        void startTimer() 
        {
            elapsedTime = 0;
            tmr.Interval = 1000;
            tmr.Start();
        }

        void stopTimer()
        {
            tmr.Stop();
        }

        void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            elapsedTime += 1;
            if (elapsedTime == 10) {
                stopTimer();
                MailSend();
            }
        }

        public void MailSend() {
            //Send mail code here
        }

        bool sendMail = false;
        protected bool SendMail
        {
            set 
            {
                if (value && !sendMail)
                    startTimer();
                else if (!value && sendMail)
                    stopTimer();

                sendMail = value; 
            }
            get { return sendMail; }
        }

        public void prepareEvent()
        {
            scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            try
            {
                query = new WqlEventQuery();
                query.EventClassName = "__InstanceOperationEvent";
                query.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                query.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NetworkAdapter' AND TargetInstance.NetConnectionStatus IS NOT NULL";
                watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
                watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(newAdapterNotifier);
                watcher.Start();                   
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
                prepareEvent();
            }
        }

        public void watcherStop()
        {
            watcher.Stop();
        }

        Ping p = new Ping();
        public HashSet<NetworkInterface> upAndReal;
        public void checkNetworkAdapters()
        {
            if (upAndReal == null)
                upAndReal = new HashSet<NetworkInterface>();
            else if (upAndReal.Count > 0)
                upAndReal.Clear();

            string desc = "";
            string name = "";

            foreach (NetworkInterface netInt in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                desc = netInt.Description;
                name = netInt.Name;

                if (netInt.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && desc.IndexOf("virtual", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0 && name.IndexOf("virtual", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0 && desc.IndexOf("Microsoft", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0 && name.IndexOf("Microsoft", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0 && (desc.IndexOf("Loopback", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0) && name.IndexOf("Loopback", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
                {
                    upAndReal.Add(netInt);
                }
            }

            if (upAndReal.Count <= 1 || (upAndReal.Count == 2 && p.Send(cameras1IP).Status == IPStatus.Success && p.Send(cameras2IP).Status == IPStatus.Success)){
                SendMail = false;
                return;
            }

            SendMail = true;
        }

        public void newAdapterNotifier(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) //Change in network
        {

            checkNetworkAdapters();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What account is the service running under, could be a permissions issue however you would expect some form of an error if that's the case.

Comment: ActiveDirectory with an administrator permission

Comment: what exception do you get? Catch exceptions and log them.

Comment: No exception.. Actually I'm good at in WinForms but new in Windows Service.. The only way to test the code that I know is installing it. So being hard it is instead of windows service I implement it in class. I may send the full code of the class.

Comment: I advise you to use Windows service for just checking your Windows application if it is running or not. Why do you want to do these things inside Windows service?

Comment: It will work as agent in my all network pcs. I shouldn't be realized by the users. And must be easy to publish on all computers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It is about the Timer. We can't use System.Windows.Forms.Timer in Windows Service.. We need to use the other ones.. But which one is it?

Comment: Ask a new question (and search SO first, before you do). Hint: look at `System.Threading.Timer`.